# Getting error in build of Android Studio app for pepper

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, pepper

I am currently trying to develop an App for a humanoid robot called pepper. But unfortunately I get stuck before I can even execute the code, which I plan to write.

This is the error message I keep getting, it seems to try to locate some poms, which might have been removed, but I am not entirely sure what exactly is failing here.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Fabian\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk/1.7.5/qisdk-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aldebaran/qisdk-design/1.7.5/qisdk-design-1.7.5.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
18 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 10 up-to-date
```

My gradle dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5'
    implementation 'com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5'
}
```

And my build gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the QiSDK is not found in all the repositories you mentioned (`google()`, `mavenCentral()`, or `jcenter()`). To get the QiSDK, add this code to your settings.gradle in `repositories {}` (IMPORTANT)

```
maven {
        url 'http://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/maven'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
```

Also, remove `jcenter()`, it is deprecated now.
Don't worry about the `allowInsecureProtocol=true` setting, the maven url is safe.
This is because the QiSDK is found in its own repo, android.aldebaran.com

Comment: Thank you, i have added the maven to repositories, as you said, synced the gradle, but still get the same error as above

Comment: I edited the main questions with the "new" error and your reccomendation to add maven

Comment: My bad, updated the answer, add this code also below the url, allowInsecureProtocol = true

Comment: No worries, the gradle file is ok, but when building the project on my emulator, i still get hit with the same error as above. It just doesnt seem to direct to aldebran

Comment: It's working fine at my place. Add the repositories {} to the build.gradle in the app folder. (Btw, it is the issue)

Comment: Still doesnt work. I followed the instructions on [link](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/starting_project.html) and cant get it to run. It runs on another computer, were i followed the exat same steps, but not on this one.

Comment: Where can i add the repositories {} to the build.gradle? shoud i add it under dependencies?

Comment: Add it separately as repositories {}

Comment: Is your project working?

Comment: Unfortunatly not.

Comment: So I think that migrating to a new project after copying all the code from a previous one would help as a new build.gradle would generate

Comment: It still doesnt seem to work,  even Softbanks doesnt know what could cause this error. I switched machines, reinstalled AS, went over the setup again and again and i allways get this error, no matter what i do. Might this have something to do with the gradle versions?

Comment: Post the new error log please, because on my computer, the build is running correctly. Upgrade to gradle 7.2.0 also

Comment: I edited the error log, though its basically the same log as a month ago

Comment: What's your gradle version?

Comment: Ok, try another way, make sure that the maven repository I gave you, android.aldebaran.com, is at the top of all other repos.

Comment: Gradle version is 7.0.2 and the maven repo is allready at the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238546/discussion-between-fabian-and-justincoding).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and had to add

```
    maven {
      url 'http://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/maven'
      allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
```

also to the settings.gradle file into `repositories{}` in `dependencyResolutionManagement{}`.